# Tag synonym/merge request: [xml-documentation] and [xmldoc]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These tags are identical, one is just a shortened (and less clear) form of the other:

- [xml-documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation) (220 questions)

  > XML documentation **are comments that form the documentation for C# programs. They are so called because they contain nested XML fragments. See Microsoft's XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide) for more details.**
- [xmldoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldoc) (41 questions)

  > XML doc (short for XML documentation comments) **are comments that form the documentation for C# programs. They are so called because they contain nested XML fragments. See Microsoft's XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide) for more details.**

Emphasis mine.

The only real difference is that [xmldoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldoc) mentions C# in the excerpt, while [xml-documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation) leaves it in the full description.

Can someone synonymize/merge these tags?  In my opinion, [xml-documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation) is the better of the two.

Comment: I'm not sure who decided that *either* of these tags are C# specific. They are certainly not. C# has not the monopoly on "XML documentation", nor even on the abbrev [xmldoc](https://www.google.com/search?q=xmldoc).